# Files that Cannot be Renamed on Mac/Mojave

Tags: mac, finder, rename

I have a number of image files that I cannot rename on my mac. Some files in the same directly can be renamed. Others cannot.

I clearly have read/write access to the directory because I can rename some files in the directory. Finder says I have read/write access to the files.

If I copy the file, I cannot rename the copy.

The problem files have the following in common:

RENAME is grayed out in the finder window when selected.
The finder preview ICON is blank rather than giving a preview of the image.
The images are readable.
The creation date for all the files is the magic Jan 24 1984.

Disk Utility shows no errors.

Comment: Open a Terminal in the folder and type `ls -al`, and share the results here (maybe just one file that you can rename, and one file you cannot, as well as the "." entry to show the folder too).

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450745/certain-files-in-finder-cannot-be-opened-renamed-tagged-although-all-permi/450746#450746

Answer (score 0):

Jan 24 1984* is the timestamp all files get when they are in the process of being written (usually as they're copied from another drive/machine otherwise it's too fast to see). This means the Mac doesn't think the write was completed & the file is not yet whole.

If you're in the middle of copying date, wait a few minutes. if you think it should have finished, or you are returning to a new session, then you may have to re-copy them from source.

A potential workaround, if it's just a failed flag & the file **is** actually complete, try Duplicating it  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>  (included for completeness, as you say you have tried this. It does work sometimes.)

*Jan 24 1984 is the release date of the very first Mac.

Comment: I have a file in my system that is behaving as the OP. From terminal I can modify it, but on Finder, I cannot open / rename it. Any updates on how to handle this?

Comment: @a06e -  If it's a failed copy, then just delete it; it doesn't really exist. Otherwise ask as a new question & link back to this one if you need to, for background.